# arduino seemingly 0 != 0

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm very confused why a simple `0 == 0` comparison doesn't seem to be working.

I have the following in my Arduino Sketch:

```
int status;

status = do_something();

if(status == 0) {
  Serial.println("status == 0");
} else {
  Serial.print("status = ");
  Serial.println(status);

  Serial.print("status (hex) = ");
  Serial.println(status, HEX);

  Serial.print("status - 5 = ");
  Serial.println(status - 5);

  Serial.print("freeMemory inside if = ");
  Serial.println(freeMemory());
}
```

What I would expect to happen is that if status is `0` then it would print out `status == 0`, but here is the actual output:

```
status = 0
status (hex) = 0
status - 5 = -5
freeMemory inside if = 1371
```

The fact that it is falling into the `else` clause implies that `status` is not zero. However, when I print the value in both decimal and hex, it is 0. I don't understand how this is possible.

I thought maybe I was running into some funky behavior due to memory issues, but you can see I have 1.3K of RAM free.

Environment:

- Mega2560
- IDE 1.8.9

Comment: Show us `do_something()`. What does it return? Perhaps you are invoking undefined behavior earlier and this is the result. A [mcve] would be wonderful.

Comment: Change the line `status = do_something();` into `status = 0;` and try again.

Comment: no matter what do_something() does, its result is stored in an int, which can be either 0 or != 0, but never both or none of both. Even if do_something() returned e.g. 
float(1E-30), this behavior is *strange*.

Comment: Are you sure you test exactly this scenario? ( There could be a global variable `status` interfering in your slightly different actual test ). BTW: cannot reproduce.